# How can I change the data of a flatlist with a function?

Tags: react-native, function, react-native-flatlist

I have an array that contains dictionaries that are represented in flatlist. Whenever I touch a component, I want to execute a function that changes the data of certain dictionaries. for example:

```
const data = [
    { duration: null, uri: null, step: 0, index: 0 }
    { duration: null, uri: null, step: 0, index: 1 }
    { duration: null, uri: null, step: 0, index: 2 }
    { duration: null, uri: null, step: 0, index: 3 }
]

const updataData = (duration, uri) => {
    duration = 1000;
    uri = 'jsdbbsljv_sjk_jka'
}

return (
    <View>
        <FlatList
            data={data}
            renderItem={itemData => (
                <View>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { updataData(itemData.item.duration, itemData.item.uri); itemData.item.step = itemData.item.step + 1 }} >
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            )}
        />
    </View>
    )
```

This isn't the code that I'm working with but the thing that I need to learn to do is to change the itemData.item values on a function outside the renderItem of the flatlist. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the state to do that (or another state management flow; like redux)
Using the state:

```js
const initialData = [
    { duration: null, uri: null, step: 0, index: 0 }
    { duration: null, uri: null, step: 0, index: 1 }
    { duration: null, uri: null, step: 0, index: 2 }
    { duration: null, uri: null, step: 0, index: 3 }
]

const [data, setData] = useState(initialData)

const updataData = (duration, uri) => {
    duration = 1000;
    uri = 'jsdbbsljv_sjk_jka'
}

const updateItem = (item, index) => {
  const updatedUri = "something here"
  data[index] = {
  ...item,
  uri: updatedUri
  }
  setData(data)
  
}


const renderItem = ({item, index}) => {
  return (
  <View>
    <TouchableOpacity 
       onPress={() => updateItem(item, index)}               
    >
   </TouchableOpacity>
   </View>
  )
 }

return (
    <View>
        <FlatList
            data={data}
            renderItem={renderItem}
        />
    </View>
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

By Storing the data in the state we can make changes into that dynamically.

We simply can pass the index of the item in the props and update the state of data on the particular index.

For Ex.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View, Text, FlatList, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";

const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([
    { duration: null, uri: null, step: 0, index: 0 },
    { duration: null, uri: null, step: 0, index: 1 },
    { duration: null, uri: null, step: 0, index: 2 },
    { duration: null, uri: null, step: 0, index: 3 }
  ]);

  const updataData = (index, duration, uri) => {
    setData((prevData) => {
      return prevData.map((item) => {
        if (item.index === index) {
          return {
            ...item,
            duration: 1000,
            uri: "jsdbbsljv_sjk_jka"
          };
        }
        return {
          ...item
        };
      });
    });
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <FlatList
        data={data}
        renderItem={(itemData) => (
          <View>
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => {
                updataData(
                  itemData.item.index,
                  itemData.item.duration,
                  itemData.item.uri
                );
                itemData.item.step = itemData.item.step + 1;
              }}
            >
              <Text>{itemData.item.duration || itemData.item.index}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```